# iOS: Stripe Apple Pay in custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I am building a framework as a part of main application. Framework looks like a single application and includes a lot of screens and logics. So the goal is to use Stripe payments inside my part without adding any logics in main app.
All tutorials tell about the Apple Pay capability inside Xcode. But in a framework  I'm not be able to add any capability. Help me out please. How should I do that? Is it possible to simple generate merchantId and use it without capability?

Comment: You could implement Stripe functionality in a framework but ultimately the app that uses your framework would need to add the Apple Pay capabilities, because entitlements and capabilities are associated with the app

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for reply. Should they know my merchant id? Or I could incapsulate it inside framework?

Comment: The app publisher will need a merchant agreement. I don't think you can provide merchant functionality to 3rd parties.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you. Will take a look